# PAM guru help to interpret system-auth password-auth RHEL 7

Tags: pam, passwd, accounts

I have a RHEL 7.9 system which currently has identical `system-auth` and `password-auth` files located under `/etc/pam.d/`.  That file is

```
auth        required      pam_faillock.so preauth audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=900 unlock_time=900
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass
auth [default=die]        pam_faillock.so authfail audit deny=3 even_deny_root fail_interval=900 unlock_time=900

auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_faildelay.so delay=2000000
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 1000 quiet_success
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     required      pam_faillock.so

account     required      pam_unix.so
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 1000 quiet
account     required      pam_permit.so


#password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so local_users_only retry=3 minlen=12 gecoscheck maxrepeat=3

password    requisite     pam_pwquality.so local_users_only retry=3 gecoscheck maxrepeat=3

password    required      pam_pwhistory.so remember=5 use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so sha512 shadow use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
-session     optional      pam_systemd.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
```

- can someone explain in understandable English what all is really happening?
- is there any bad or incorrect items?
- is the `minlen=12` and `maxrepeat=3` of any purpose when they are defined in `/etc/security/pwquality.conf`  { and `/etc/login.defs` for minlen } ?